# Symfony init:acl command missing

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to use Symfony's ACL system but I am unable to initialize the database.  I followed the steps here [How to Use Access Control List (ACL's)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/acl.html), but when I run the console command I get `There are no commands defined in the "init" namespace.`

I have the SecurityBundle defined in my AppKernel `new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle()`.  And here is my security.yml

```
# security.yml
security:
    acl:
        connection: default
```

I'm not quite understanding what I'm missing.  I do understand though that it's likely a configuration issue.  Looking at the Command in symfony's library I see

```
<?php
class InitAclCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isEnabled()
    {
        if (!$this->getContainer()->has('security.acl.dbal.connection')) {
            return false;
        }

        return parent::isEnabled();
    }
    //...
}
```

My guess is `isEnabled()` is returning false, but I'm not sure what or where I set the configuration for this.

I am using Symfony 3.1.9 and PHP7.0

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check you have the following package installed:

```
composer require symfony/security-acl
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands:

```
composer require symfony/security-acl
```

Then:

```
composer update
```

Then run:

```
php bin/console init:acl
```

That should work

Comment: Facing the same issue, but with symfony 4, it's quite different I think to solve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113469/install-security-acl-inside-symfony-4