# Install Security-acl inside Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, composer-php, acl

Trying to make this command work while I'm getting the error :

```
php bin/console init:acl
```

> Symfony init:acl command missing

I found this stack issue answering: [Symfony init:acl command missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41856533/symfony-initacl-command-missing)

Problem is, when I try to

```
composer require symfony/security-acl
```

I'm getting

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>     Could not find package symfony/security-acl in a version matching 4.3.*

Which seems to be normal as acl support were removed from Symfony 4 and even 3 I think.
But still, it seems to be possible to use it according to the Symfony SonataAdminBundle.

I don't know how to fix this, thanks for your help

EDIT: ACL bundle install

```
$ composer require symfony/acl-bundle
Using version ^1.0 for symfony/acl-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.3.*"
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
ocramius/package-versions: Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Executing script assets:install public [OK]
```

EDIT2:

Print

```
chris@LAPTOP-JDR0HFFT MINGW64 ~/Desktop/projets/cav-php (acl_test)
$ git checkout -- .

chris@LAPTOP-JDR0HFFT MINGW64 ~/Desktop/projets/cav-php (acl_test)
$ git status
On branch acl_test
nothing to commit, working tree clean


chris@LAPTOP-JDR0HFFT MINGW64 ~/Desktop/projets/cav-php (acl_test)
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.3.*"
Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 1 removal
**- Removing symfony/acl-bundle (v1.0.1)**
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
ocramius/package-versions: Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Executing script assets:install public [OK]


chris@LAPTOP-JDR0HFFT MINGW64 ~/Desktop/projets/cav-php (acl_test)
$ php bin/console cache:clear

 // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true


 [OK] Cache for the "dev" environment (debug=true) was successfully cleared.



chris@LAPTOP-JDR0HFFT MINGW64 ~/Desktop/projets/cav-php (acl_test)
$ composer require symfony/acl-bundle
Using version ^1.0 for symfony/acl-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.3.*"
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
**- Installing symfony/acl-bundle (v1.0.1): Loading from cache**
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
ocramius/package-versions: Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Symfony operations: 1 recipe (a8cc43db8a7843044a16dd2afc8ce860)
- Configuring symfony/acl-bundle (>=v1.0.1): From auto-generated recipe
Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Executing script assets:install public [OK]

Some files may have been created or updated to configure your new packages.
Please review, edit and commit them: these files are yours.


chris@LAPTOP-JDR0HFFT MINGW64 ~/Desktop/projets/cav-php (acl_test)
$ php bin/console cache:clear

// Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true


[OK] Cache for the "dev" environment (debug=true) was successfully cleared.



chris@LAPTOP-JDR0HFFT MINGW64 ~/Desktop/projets/cav-php (acl_test)
$ php bin/console init:acl


 **There are no commands defined in the "init" namespace.**
```

Comment: It seems that the problem can be solved by removing all the bundle and reinstalling them

Comment: Looks like it's not working for me, see the print. Or may be I have to undo all install...even SonataAdmin..but in the end I will reach the same point, that's why I don't really understand, and I don't see why I would but ACL before the admin.

Comment: You should follow @Bananaapple 's suggestion. That should work.

Answer (score 2):

The Sonata documentation isn't always fully up to date due to being maintained by a relatively small number of people.

You should still be able to use use https://github.com/symfony/acl-bundle according to https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/acl.html

`composer require symfony/acl-bundle`

Details for using that are here: https://github.com/symfony/acl-bundle/blob/master/src/Resources/doc/index.rst

Comment: I already have required that bundle but after I'm getting the error I show above with init:acl

Comment: Are you sure you installed `symfony/acl-bundle` @Minirock? Your question suggests you installed `symfony/security-acl`. If I install `symfony/acl-bundle` I can run `acl:init` on S4 no problem...

Comment: Well I have this in my bundle.php so yes i'm pretty sure `    Symfony\Bundle\AclBundle\AclBundle::class => ['all' => true],` and he is in the vendor too...and in my composer.json I have : "symfony/acl-bundle": "^1.0",

Comment: If it installs properly without errors the command should be available. Did you clear your cache? If that doesn't work you could try to remove everything acl related and retry. I am reasonably certain that it should work on 4.3 as I had no trouble installing it just there on an existing project of mine to test.

Comment: Still the same I went back on my branch be sure it was deleted...re-installed...and still not working

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so looks like the command isn't

```
php bin/console init:acl
```

but

```
php bin/console acl:init
```

Which isn't said in the doc :(